In Catholic atonement theology, if God can save Mary from all sin without Christ, what was the point of Christ's death?
It is my understanding that in Catholic Theology the immaculate conception relates to the fact that Mary was born without the blemish of original sin. It is also my understanding that Mary was, through the grace of God, kept from ever committing any personal sin as well.
As a Protestant, I have a hard time understanding how these dogmas do not completely negate the need for a savior for not only Mary but every human. If God can save one person from original sin and personal sin without the death of Jesus Christ why not everyone? How does the Catholic atonement theology address this?

The title of the question suggests that you think God saved Mary from all sin without Christ. This is not the Catholic view. Here is the crucial passage from the papal decree, Ineffabilis Deus, defining the dogma of the immaculate conception [emphasis added by me]:

“We declare, pronounce, and define that the doctrine which holds that the most Blessed Virgin Mary, in the first instance of her conception, by a singular grace and privilege granted by Almighty God, in view of the merits of Jesus Christ, the Savior of the human race, was preserved free from all stain of original sin, is a doctrine revealed by God and therefore to be believed firmly and constantly by all the faithful.”


So, the Saviour that Mary was referring to at Magnificat is not Jesus but God the Father, as She said "my spirit rejoices in God my saviour..". At this moment, Mary was already saved, and very clearly, God the Father is the Saviour, as He was the one who applied the merit of Christ, if we follow the dogmatic definition of the Catholic Church. Do you agree?

@jongricafort what exactly do you mean? The dogma here just says "Almighty God," and any act of God is participated in by all three Persons of the Holy Trinity. There is no sense in which the Father does something that the Son and Holy Spirit do not, only that certain acts are appropriated to certain persons. Only, of course, the Son assumed a human nature, and as man did things which the Father and Holy Spirit do not, since they have no bodies.

@jaredad7 Jesus humanity enters time, and the merit of Christ was applied eventhough in reality it does not exist yet. Who do you think, was the one who applied the merit of Christ to the soul of Mary, if not God the Father? First, incarnated Logos does not enters time time yet, and the Holy Spirit was not even sent yet.

@jongricafort all three Persons exist in eternity. All three applied the future merits of Christ incarnate to Mary, though the act may or may not be rightly appropriated to God the Father. If you just mean to say the act is rightly appropriated to the Father, as the act of creation is, you might be correct. If, however, you are saying that the Son and the Holy Spirit do not act to save Mary, you are incorrect, for the whole Divine Essence is One and acts as One. https://www.newadvent.org/summa/1039.htm#article1

@jaredad7 "by a singular grace and privilege granted by Almighty God". The Father applied the merit of Christ, Jesus offered Himself as the sacrifice and the Holy Spirit sanctifed it. But, let's dig in deeper, was Mary like the Jews in the Old Testament, look upon God as "Abba Father"? When Mary uttered the Magnificat, was She referring only to God the Father?

@jongricafort these appropriations of acts to the Divine Persons are correct, but I push back because you seem to be excluding the Son and the Holy Spirit from paritcipation in applying the merit, which is incorrect. I say this because of your comment on the question, which says "Her Saviour is God the Father not Jesus alone or directly, as the Father is the one who applied the merit of Christ to Her soul" It is the word "not" that causes contention here. Father, Son, and Holy Spirit act as One. There is nothing one does (besides the Son as man) that the others do not do.

The question about the Magnificat can be taken to a chat, if you like, but I think it's important to leave the discussion of the Trinity acting here as a public discussion, because it is important to correct the misunderstanding that could arise from your presentation.

Thank you for this answer, this makes sense to me. I was assuming that the grace given to Mary was outside of Christ because one of my Catholic friends had said so. Thank you for clearing this up for me though

The point of Christ's death was that God ordained from eternity to will the salvation of the world consequent upon the willing sacrifice of Christ. Indeed, Mariologists would hold that this same sacrifice is what preserved Mary from original sin, but retroactively.
Catholics understand God as having the power to redeem all men without any incarnation or material acts, but that this would not be fitting, and He ordains to do so through Christ's sacrifice. Because He ordains to do so through Christ's sacrifice, that sacrifice bears a kind of necessity, though not of an absolute character, as the cause of mankind's salvation. St. Thomas Aquinas puts it this way:

I answer that, As the Philosopher teaches (Metaph. v), there are several acceptations of the word "necessary." In one way it means anything which of its nature cannot be otherwise; and in this way it is evident that it was not necessary either on the part of God or on the part of man for Christ to suffer. In another sense a thing may be necessary from some cause quite apart from itself... But if the external factor which induces necessity be an end, then it will be said to be necessary from presupposing such end—namely, when some particular end cannot exist at all, or not conveniently, except such end be presupposed. It was not necessary, then, for Christ to suffer from necessity of compulsion, either on God's part, who ruled that Christ should suffer, or on Christ's own part, who suffered voluntarily. Yet it was necessary from necessity of the end proposed; and this can be accepted in three ways. First of all, on our part, who have been delivered by His Passion, according to John (3:14): "The Son of man must be lifted up, that whosoever believeth in Him may not perish, but may have life everlasting." Secondly, on Christ's part, who merited the glory of being exalted, through the lowliness of His Passion: and to this must be referred Luke 24:26: "Ought not Christ to have suffered these things, and so to enter into His glory?" Thirdly, on God's part, whose determination regarding the Passion of Christ, foretold in the Scriptures and prefigured in the observances of the Old Testament, had to be fulfilled. And this is what St. Luke says (22:22): "The Son of man indeed goeth, according to that which is determined"; and (Luke 24:44-46): "These are the words which I spoke to you while I was yet with you, that all things must needs be fulfilled which are written in the law of Moses, and in the prophets, and in the psalms concerning Me: for it is thus written, and thus it behooved Christ to suffer, and to rise again from the dead." ST III Q46 A1 co


I really like the word "fitting", which is explained in depth in this 2 part lecture on Aquinas's view of the Incarnation and its relation to Christ's death on the cross: part 1, part 2.

Citing Aquinas who fell short of understanding how the Immaculate Conception happened is not "fitting". The wisdom of a " Subtle Doctor over Angelic Doctor" is a more appropriate citation. God Divine Plan for the Salvation of Man originated from incarnating the Logos, thus the Immaculate Conception is a necessity. Genesis1:1 the word Bereshit means "Way of the Cross"., Lucia's last vision of Mary and Jesus at the Foot of the Cross, is the Salvation Plan. That's why, God conception of Mary in eternity encompasses the whole plan of man's salvation.

"God Divine Plan for the Salvation of Man originated from incarnating the Logos, thus the Immaculate Conception is a necessity." No.  Thus the Virgin Birth of Christ is the necessity.  The Immaculate Conception of Mary is invented due to a misunderstanding of the nature of sin and it's transmission.

@jongricafort the question is more about how Mary is preserved from sin through Christ's sacrifice than it is about the Immaculate Conception per se. Besides, those who say Aquinas got the Immaculate Conception "wrong" fail to understand precisely what the terms involved mean, both for him and for Pius IX.

@MikeBorden jong is incorrect to say that the Immaculate Conception is a necessity, if what he means is an absolute or logical necessity for the virgin birth or incarnation to take place. Nevertheless, the doctrine is not invented, and is rooted in the beliefs of the Early Church, though the doctrine developed over time, as many do. Mary's Immaculate Conception is a relative necessity on account of the fact that God actively wills it. https://www.catholic.com/tract/mary-full-of-grace

@MikeBorden Can you tell us the difference between "immaculately conceived" and "Immaculate Conception"?

@jaredad7 Was Mary immaculately conceived or the Immaculate Conception? This is where the wrong understanding starts. When, Bernadette asked, "Who are you? "... Mary answered, " I am the Immaculate Conceotion".Now, is "Immaculate Conception" a divine person or a description of Mary's birth?

@jongricafort the Immaculate Conception as a term can refer to both the event of Mary's being immaculately conceived and to Mary herself.

In Catholic atonement theology, if God can save Mary from all sin without Christ, what was the point of Christ's death?
It is held to be true, according to the Catholic Church, that Mary was immaculately conceived and thus preserved from original sin and all it’s consequences. Nevertheless this does not mean that Mary was preserved from being tempted, just like the rest of humanity. Mary worked efficaciously with the Divine graces given to her by almighty God. Christ still saved Mary, albeit in a more unique and intimate manner.
It is true that according to Catholicism, Mary is believed to be immaculately conceived and did not commit any real personal sin, but these graces did not preserve Mary from being tempted to sin.
Jesus himself was tempted in the ways men are; then logic tells us that his Mother would have been equally tempted as men are.

For we have not a high priest, who can not have compassion on our infirmities: but one tempted in all things like as we are, without sin. - Hebrews 4:15

Mary's Immaculate Conception was not necessary for our salvation!

The Catholic Church believes that it was not absolutely or intrinsically necessary for the Blessed Virgin Mary to be sinless; only fitting or appropriate (God making the choice).
Thus, even a dogmatic belief in the Immaculate Conception does not in any way impinge upon the Two Natures of Christ. We believe the Immaculate Conception happened, and are required to believe this, but we don't believe that it had to happen exactly as it did (in all possible worlds, etc.), in order for God to be God.
All the Immaculate Conception did was make Mary as Eve was before the Fall (precisely why the Church fathers often called her the Second Eve or New Eve): unfallen and sinless; not subject to original sin. As Cardinal Newman remarked, "Why is it considered such an extraordinary thing that God chose to simply make one person—the Mother of God the Son, the Theotokos—the way that all of us would have been, but for the Fall?"
Fr. Ryan Erlenbush wrote on The New Theological Movement website (12-8-11):

And this is the great difference between Jesus and Mary: She required a special grace to preserve her from the stain of sin, but our Savior (by virtue of the Incarnation itself, and on account of his divinity) could not possibly have contracted the guilt or debt of original sin in any respect.


While our Blessed Lady, even though Immaculately Conceived, required a Redeemer (namely, her own Son, Christ Jesus), the Lord did not have any need of a Redeemer. No special grace was required (beyond that of the Incarnation itself) to keep the Christ Child from original sin – he could not possibly have contracted it.


In this sense, the dogma of the Immaculate Conception is seen to be fitting and true while (in itself) not absolutely necessary, but the sinlessness of the Lord Jesus is absolutely necessary and super-eminently fitting.

Was Mary's Immaculate Conception Absolutely Necessary?

St. Thomas Aquinas maintains that it was indeed possible for Our Lord Jesus Christ to have been born of sinful woman; Christ's glory would not have been diminished thereby. But, he states elsewhere, it would have been inappropriate:

God so prepares and endows those, whom He chooses for some particular office, that they are rendered capable of fulfilling it, according to 2 Cor. 3:6: "(Who) hath made us fit ministers of the New Testament." Now the Blessed Virgin was chosen by God to be His Mother. Therefore there can be no doubt that God, by His grace, made her worthy of that office. ... But she would not have been worthy to be the Mother of God, if she had ever sinned. First, because the honor of the parents reflects on the child, according to Prov. 17:6: "The glory of children are their fathers": and consequently, on the other hand, the Mother's shame would have reflected on her Son. Secondly, because of the singular affinity between her and Christ, who took flesh from her: and it is written (2 Cor. 6:15): "What concord hath Christ with Belial?" Thirdly, because of the singular manner in which the Son of God, who is the "Divine Wisdom" (1 Cor. 1:24) dwelt in her, not only in her soul but in her womb. And it is written (Wis. 1:4): "Wisdom will not enter into a malicious soul, nor dwell in a body subject to sins."
We must therefore confess simply that the Blessed Virgin committed no actual sin, neither mortal nor venial; so that what is written (Cant 4:7) is fulfilled: "Thou art all fair, O my love, and there is not a spot in thee," etc. - Was the dogma of the Immaculate Conception formulated in response to someone challenging Mary's ability to bear a perfect Son?

If God preserved Mary from all sin, He could have preserved Christ's body and soul likewise without the grace of Mary's Immaculate Conception.

Was it necessary for God to make Mary immaculate at her conception so that she could be Jesus' mother?
No. The Church only speaks of the Immaculate Conception as something that was "fitting," something that made Mary a "fit habitation" (i.e., suitable dwelling) for the Son of God, not something that was necessary.

And hence they [the Church Fathers] affirmed that the Blessed Virgin was, through grace, entirely free from every stain of sin, and from all corruption of body, soul and mind; that she was always united with God and joined to him by an eternal covenant; that she was never in darkness but always in light; and that, therefore, she was entirely a fit habitation for Christ, not because of the state of her body, but because of her original grace. . . .


For it was certainly not fitting that this vessel of election should be wounded by the common injuries, since she, differing so much from the others, had only nature in common with them, not sin. In fact, it was quite fitting that, as the Only-Begotten has a Father in heaven, whom the Seraphim extol as thrice holy, so he should have a Mother on earth who would never be without the splendor of holiness - (Ineffabilis Deus).


St. Thomas Aquinas in his Summa clearly states that it was Adam and not Eve that was responsible for the transition of original sin. Now if Mary, the Mother of Jesus is the New Eve and Jesus Christ is the New Adam, it is obvious that the Immaculate Conception was not necessary for our salvation for the Holy Spirit can operate in that dwelling place He so chooses to. It the Holy Spirit that made it possible for Christ to be free of original sin and not Mary, the New Eve.

The solution of this question is made clear by what has been said. For it has been stated that original sin is transmitted by the first parent in so far as he is the mover in the begetting of his children: wherefore it has been said that if anyone were begotten materially only, of human flesh, they would not contract original sin. Now it is evident that in the opinion of philosophers, the active principle of generation is from the father, while the mother provides the matter. Therefore original sin, is contracted, not from the mother, but from the father: so that, accordingly, if Eve, and not Adam, had sinned, their children would not contract original sin: whereas, if Adam, and not Eve, had sinned, they would contract it. - Whether if Eve, and not Adam, had sinned, their children would have contracted original sin?

Thus Mary, like all of mankind, was saved by Christ’s victory over death on the Cross, albeit through special graces received by the Mother of Jesus.
Mary’s own victory is none other than Christ’s Victory. No other person had the possibility of offering their son’s death to God for the salvation of the world as Mary did at the foot of the Cross.

Is Mary being sinless throughout her life part of the dogma of Immaculate Conception, part of some other Marian dogma, part of another doctrine, or not a doctrine but an assertion of non-binding theology?

@GratefulDisciple It's a dogmatic teaching found in Lumen Gentium Chapter 8.

@GratefulDisciple It is not part of the dogma of the Immaculate conception, it is part of the of the dogma of Mary's assumption into heaven.

In Catholic atonement theology, if God can save Mary from all sin without Christ, what was the point of Christ's death?
In Catholic Theology, Mary was redeemed in a more exalted fashion.

492 The "splendor of an entirely unique holiness" by which Mary is "enriched from the first instant of her conception" comes wholly from Christ: she is "redeemed, in a more exalted fashion, by reason of the merits of her Son." The Father blessed Mary more than any other created person "in Christ with every spiritual blessing in the heavenly places" and chose her "in Christ before the foundation of the world, to be holy and blameless before him in love."

All mankind were redeemed, but the question is, what is the meaning of "exalted fashion"?
St. John the Baptist was redeemed and sanctified right at the very womb of Elizabeth, how about the future Mother of God?
The Dogma of Immaculate Conception stated, at the "first instance of conception..."
So, we can see that the exalted fashion pointed to, how Mary's dignity surpasses John the Baptist.
But the question is, who is the one who conceived Mary?
Is the dogma referring to conception of St. Anne or referring to conception of Almighty God from all eternity?
Answer pointed to Mary's predestination.

....from all eternity God chose for the mother of his Son a daughter of Israel, a young Jewish woman of Nazareth in Galilee..."


Mary's predestination


488 "God sent forth his Son," but to prepare a body for him, he wanted the free co-operation of a creature. For this, from all eternity God chose for the mother of his Son a daughter of Israel, a young Jewish woman of Nazareth in Galilee, "a virgin betrothed to a man whose name was Joseph, of the house of David; and the virgin's name was Mary":

Almighty was the one who conceived Mary's existence from "all eternity", meaning, when the Dogma of Immaculate Conception stated, "at the first instance of conception", it is pointing to Almighty God conceiving, and not to St. Anne conception.
That's why in Catholic Theology, it teaches, Mary's dignity surpasses all mankind including the Heavenly Host, because Mary existed before creation time begins, in the heart of God, where He conceived the chosen Woman, the future Mother of God.
Ave!
Back to the OP question...

In Catholic atonement theology, if God can save Mary from all sin without Christ, what was the point of Christ's death?

The question misrepresented Catholic Theology, as the Catholic Church stated Mary was redeemed or saved, by applying the merit of Christ, in a more exalted fashion.
The most important question is, when was exactly the merit of Christ applied to Mary?
Answer: Right from the very seed, right from the very sperm of St. Joachim.

"St. Joachim poured-out a spotless seed/sperm." - St. John of Damscus"

And this can be supported by scriptures in Psalm 139:16
And if one can deeply ponder this profound commentary on Psalm 139:16, it pointed to unformed substance, whom God saw from eternity, pointing to redemption right at the very seed or sperm, and also, the commentary pointed to "mantle of Elijah", that is connected to Our Lady.

In a biblical sense, mantle can imply a covering of grace, a specific calling on our lives, as in Elijah's prophetic mantle falling onto Elisha in a literal and metaphorical handing over of his cloak and anointing. Mary, the Mother of Jesus, was cloaked and enveloped by God's grace. - Mantle: Mary’s covering and our own God-given calling.

Here's is Benson Commentary pointing to Psalm 139:16 citing "mantle of Elijah".

Barnes' Notes on the Bible
Thine eyes did see my substance, yet being unperfect - This whole verse is very obscure, but the "idea" in this expression clearly is, "Before I had shape or form thou didst see what I was to be." The single word in the original translated "my substance, yet being unperfect," is גלם gôlem. It occurs only in this place, though the verb - גלם gâlam - is found in 2 Kings 2:8, where it is used in reference to the mantle of Elijah: And Elijah took his mantle, and "wrapped it together," etc. That is, he rolled it up, or he folded it. The noun, then, means that which "is" rolled or wrapped together; that which is folded up, and hence, is applicable to anything folded up or undeveloped; and would thus most aptly denote the embryo, or the foetus, where all the members of the body are as yet folded up, or undeveloped; that is, before they have assumed their distinct form and proportions. This is undoubtedly the idea here. Before the embryo had any such form that its future size, shape, or proportions could be marked by the eye of man, it was clearly and distinctly known by God.
And in thy book - Where thou recordest all things. Perhaps the allusion here would be to the book of an architect or draftsman, who, before his work is begun, draws his plan, or sketches it for the direction of the workmen.
All my members were written - The words "my members" are not in the original. The Hebrew is, as in the margin, "all of them." The reference may be, not to the members of his body, but to his "days" (see the margin on the succeeding phrase) - and then the sense would be, all my "days," or all the periods of my life, were delineated in thy book. That is, When my substance - my form - was not yet developed, when yet an embryo, and when nothing could be determined from that by the eye of man as to what I was to be, all the future was known to God, and was written down - just what should be my form and vigor; how long I should live; what I should be; what would be the events of my life.
Which in continuance were fashioned - Margin, "What days they should be fashioned." Literally, "Days should be formed." DeWette renders this, "The days were determined before any one of them was." There is nothing in the Hebrew to correspond with the phrase "in continuance." The simple idea is, The days of my life were determined on, the whole matter was fixed and settled, not by anything seen in the embryo, but "before" there was any form - before there were any means of judging from what I then was to what I would be - all was seen and arranged in the divine mind.
When as yet there was none of them - literally, "And not one among them." Before there was one of them in actual existence. Not one development had yet occurred from which it could be inferred what the rest would be. The entire knowledge on the subject must have been based on Omniscience. - Barnes' Notes on the Bible

The words from the commentary, Thine eyes did see my substance, yet being unperfect..and next is...""Before I had shape or form thou didst see what I was to be."
St. John of Damascus teaching on "spotless seed/sperm", pointed to a substance not being perfect or not yet in union with an egg cell.
And this teaching is supported by Bl. Emmerich vision, seeing St. Joachim concupiscence was healed when an angel gave him a "wheat and grape wine", a symbol of the Holy Eucharist.
In closing, the Blessed Virgin Mary was redeemed in a more exalted fashion, right at the very seed or sperm of St. Joachim.
So for all the Protestant, who look upon Mary as a sinner in need of a Saviour, your theology is obviously wrong.
Mary never contracted the original sin, and never committed a single sin.

I would not say in a more exalted way, but that Mary was saved in a more unique manner.

@KenGraham Thats the inspired wisdom to the Magisterium of the Catholic Church coming from the Holy Spirit. I would say, putting a different word like "unique" over "exalted", is like a mistranslation of the bible, deviating from the Wisdom of God. Why exalted? Because a Sovereign Queen must be exalted,. Otherwise St. Gabriel bowing down is a miss. -Ave!

"All mankind were redeemed" the reprobate are not redeemed. You don't actually answer how the merits of Christ (which is via the Passion) are applied to Mary. You make a big fuss about the when which isn't in dispute.

Christ died and rose. By dying, he accepted the penalty of sin on the whole  human race. By rising, he opened heaven and freed the dead. What I've been taught by my pastor is that he had to be born of a woman without sin, and yet Mary was still preserved by the merits of his Passion. How? Because God, who is timeless, knows what He is doing, and therefore advanced to her that which had not yet occurred within time- freedom from sin.
Think of it like a credit card. You can buy things before payday, and then when you have the money you pay the credit card company the price of the thing they paid for when you used the card.
In this case, Mary's state of perfection was advanced to her, like the purchase on the credit card, but the debt of credit was still paid by her Son.
Why advance it to her? Because it would be inappropriate for Him to come through a means less than perfect, because He always does things in the best possible way, even when we don't understand them.
And coming through a mortal stained by sin would be a less suitable means to open our Salvation. A woman suffering Original Sin, as all did and do before baptism, is not united to God as Adam and Eve were before the Fall. By the advance grace given to Mary by the passion of her Son, she was as wholly in tune with Him as Adam once was, before Satan and the Tree.
